# How to identify unknown compression algorithm?

Tags: compression

I'm trying to parse some text information from within project files of an Adobe program (Adobe Premiere Pro). The project files are `gzip` compressed XML files. These then contain fields which have `base64` encoded fields which contain further information about a component of the project. I'm trying to look at the information within these fields.

I can't for the life of me identify the compression scheme used here. It doesn't look like GZip as it doesn't have the appropriate headers. Can anyone help?

An example of a `base64` encoded field is:

> 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

Comment: So I've been snooping a bit at this. I'm pretty sure this is zlib, but starting after the first byte. There's a magic byte pairing 78 9C starting at the 33rd byte. I'll do more digging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Zlib-compressed string with a 32-byte uncompressed header.

```
 var encoding = @"";
        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(encoding);
        var compressedArray = new byte[data.Length - 32];
        Array.Copy(data, 32, compressedArray, 0, data.Length - 32);
        var decompressed = ZlibStream.UncompressBuffer(compressedArray);
        var str = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decompressed);
```

The header contains the uncompressed length of the data in little-endian order at offset 8: `a5 d5` or `0xd5a4`, which equals 54692. It is hard to tell from this example if the uncompressed length is stored as `a5 d5`, `a5 d5 00 00`, or `a5 d5 00 00 00 00 00 00`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python version for [Mark Adler's algorithm in C# with the DotNetZip library](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38027946/revisions):

```py
import base64
import zlib

b64decoded = base64.b64decode(strangeString)

zlibdecompressed = zlib.decompress(b64decoded[32:])
print(zlibdecompressed.decode('utf-16le'))
```

Here is an example XML result for the question's hash:

````xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" ?><Adobe_Root><Adobe_Title><Version>20080702</Version><Motion_Settings><Play_Forward>true</Play_Forward><Start_on_Screen>false</Start_on_Screen><Pre_Roll>0</Pre_Roll><Ease_In>0</Ease_In><End_off_Screen>false</End_off_Screen><Post_Roll>0</Post_Roll><Ease_Out>0</Ease_Out></Motion_Settings></Adobe_Title><InscriberLayouts Version="1.0"><Layout><LayoutEffectInfo Version="2"><EffectType>0</EffectType><Indic>false</Indic></LayoutEffectInfo><LayoutDimension Version="2"><pXPIXELS>1920</pXPIXELS><pYLINES>1080</pYLINES><pSCREENAR>1</pSCREENAR><growthDirection>growRightDown</growthDirection></LayoutDimension><LayoutAttributes><SafeTitleArea><left>0.1</left><top>0.1</top><right>0.9</right><bottom>0.9</bottom></SafeTitleArea><SafeActionArea><left>0.05</left><top>0.05</top><right>0.95</right><bottom>0.95</bottom></SafeActionArea></LayoutAttributes><Background Version="4"><ShaderReference>4098</ShaderReference><On>false</On><paintingRange>normalLayout</paintingRange></Background><DefaultStyle><Reference>4098</Reference></DefaultStyle><DefaultTextDescription><Reference>4098</Reference></DefaultTextDescription><GraphicObjectDefaults><endCapType>square</endCapType><joinTypeClosed>round</joinTypeClosed><joinTypeOpen>round</joinTypeOpen><lineWidth>5</lineWidth><miterLimit>5</miterLimit><windBeziers>false</windBeziers><roundCornerFillets>37.5 37.5 37.5 37.5 37.5 37.5 37.5 37.5 </roundCornerFillets><clippedCornerFillets>37.5 37.5 37.5 37.5 37.5 37.5 37.5 37.5 </clippedCornerFillets></GraphicObjectDefaults><TextChainDefaults><normal><leading>0</leading><boxCanGrow>false</boxCanGrow><wordWrap>true</wordWrap><lockedLinesX>false</lockedLinesX><lockedLinesY>false</lockedLinesY><Alignment>left</Alignment><tabModeStyle>Word</tabModeStyle><implicitTabSpacing>100</implicitTabSpacing><implicitTabType>left</implicitTabType><tabs></tabs></normal><boxNormal><leading>0</leading><boxCanGrow>false</boxCanGrow><wordWrap>true</wordWrap><lockedLinesX>true</lockedLinesX><lockedLinesY>true</lockedLinesY><Alignment>left</Alignment><tabModeStyle>Word</tabModeStyle><implicitTabSpacing>100</implicitTabSpacing><implicitTabType>left</implicitTabType><tabs></tabs></boxNormal><blockNormal><leading>0</leading><boxCanGrow>false</boxCanGrow><wordWrap>false</wordWrap><lockedLinesX>true</lockedLinesX><lockedLinesY>true</lockedLinesY><Alignment>left</Alignment><tabModeStyle>Word</tabModeStyle><implicitTabSpacing>100</implicitTabSpacing><implicitTabType>left</implicitTabType><tabs></tabs></blockNormal><spline><leading>0</leading><boxCanGrow>false</boxCanGrow><wordWrap>false</wordWrap><lockedLinesX>false</lockedLinesX><lockedLinesY>false</lockedLinesY><Alignment>left</Alignment><tabModeStyle>Word</tabModeStyle><implicitTabSpacing>100</implicitTabSpacing><implicitTabType>left</implicitTabType><tabs></tabs></spline></TextChainDefaults><TextDescriptions Version="4"><TextDescription Reference="4096"><TypeSpec><size>360</size><txHeight>47```
````

Comment: This technique is used in this Github project as well: https://github.com/ubershmekel/pytitle/blob/eea4631c7302b734ba8407b16583a6a2b5aa6943/prpoj_to_srt/timings_from_prproj.py#L91